# This C program stops getting input in the middle of the work. I get a segmentation fault (core dumped). Still don't know the problem

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, input, segmentation-fault

Before starting the discussion, I'm a begginer to C programming and pointers. :)

**Edit: My problem has been resolved and I've put the final code and the desctiptions in the answers section below.**

This code is supposed to get a matrix and manipulate it in the way user desires by the defined functions. But the input process doesn't work properly and crashes in the middle. I got `segmentation fault (core dumped)` from one of the compilers. But don't know even where this kind of problem can lie. Thanks indeed for your response cause it's been hours since I have been working on debugging.

Here's the code: **(first part of the code is related to the matrix-manipulation functions - which in some them also some inputs may be taken - but the whole process of taking inputs is in the main function. So it may not be needed to read the whole code)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_matrix(int *matrix, int row, int column) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i * column + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void ravel(int *matrix, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (*row_address) * (*column_address); i++) {
        printf("%d ", matrix[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void reshape(int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    scanf(" %d %d", row_address, column_address);
}

void resize(int **matrix_address, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    int first_size = (*row_address) * (*column_address);
    scanf(" %d %d", row_address, column_address);
    *matrix_address = (int *)realloc(*matrix_address, (*row_address) * (*column_address) * sizeof(int));
    for (int iterator = first_size; iterator < (*row_address) * (*column_address); iterator++) {
        (*matrix_address)[iterator] = (*matrix_address)[iterator % first_size];
    }
}

void append_row(int **matrix_address, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    int row[*column_address];
    for (int k = 0; k < *column_address; k++) {
        scanf(" %d", &row[k]);
    }
    *matrix_address = (int *)realloc(*matrix_address, ((*row_address) + 1) * (*column_address) * sizeof(int));
    for (int j = 0; j < (*column_address); j++) {
        (*matrix_address)[(*row_address) * (*column_address) + j] = row[j];
    }
    (*row_address)++;
}

void insert_row(int *matrix, int **matrix_address, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    int insert;
    scanf(" %d", &insert);
    int row[*column_address];
    for (int k = 0; k < *column_address; k++) {
        scanf(" %d", &row[k]);
    }
    *matrix_address = (int *)realloc(*matrix_address, ((*row_address) + 1) * (*column_address) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < insert; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *column_address; j++) {
            (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address) + j] = matrix[i * (*column_address) + j];
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < *column_address; k++) {
        (*matrix_address)[insert * (*column_address) + k] = row[k];
    }
    for (int i = insert + 1; i < *row_address + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *column_address; j++)  {
            (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address) + j] = matrix[(i - 1) * (*column_address) + j];
        }
    }
    (*row_address)++;
}

void append_column(int *matrix, int **matrix_address, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    int column[*row_address];
    for (int k = 0; k < *row_address; k++) {
        scanf(" %d", &column[k]);
    }
    *matrix_address = (int *)realloc(*matrix_address, (*row_address) * ((*column_address) + 1) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < *row_address; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *column_address; j++) {
            (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address + 1) + j] = matrix[i * (*column_address) + j];
        }
        (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address + 1) + (*column_address)] = column[i];
    }
    (*column_address)++;
}

void insert_column(int *matrix, int **matrix_address, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    int insert;
    scanf(" %d", &insert);
    int column[*row_address];
    for (int k = 0; k < *row_address; k++) {
        scanf(" %d", &column[k]);
    }
    *matrix_address = (int *)realloc(*matrix_address, (*row_address) * ((*column_address) + 1) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < *row_address; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < insert; j++) {
            (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address + 1) + j] = matrix[i * (*column_address) + j];
        }
        (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address + 1) + insert] = column[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < *row_address; i++) {
        for (int j = insert + 1; j < *column_address + 1; j++)  {
            (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address + 1) + j] = matrix[i * (*column_address) + j - 1];
        }
    }
    (*column_address)++;
}

void delete_row(int *matrix, int **matrix_address, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    int delete;
    scanf(" %d", &delete);
    for (int i = 0; i < delete; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *column_address; j++) {
            (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address) + j] = matrix[i * (*column_address) + j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = delete; i < *row_address - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *column_address; j++)  {
            (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address) + j] = matrix[(i + 1) * (*column_address) + j];
        }
    }
    *matrix_address = (int *)realloc(*matrix_address, (*row_address - 1) * (*column_address) * sizeof(int));
    (*row_address)--;
}

void delete_column(int *matrix, int **matrix_address, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    int delete;
    scanf(" %d", &delete);
    for (int i = 0; i < *row_address; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < delete; j++) {
            (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address - 1) + j] = matrix[i * (*column_address) + j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < *row_address; i++) {
        for (int j = delete; j < *column_address - 1; j++)  {
            (*matrix_address)[i * ((*column_address) - 1) + j] = matrix[i * (*column_address) + j + 1];
        }
    }
    *matrix_address = (int *)realloc(*matrix_address, (*row_address) * (*column_address - 1) * sizeof(int));
    (*column_address)--;
}

void tile(int *matrix, int **matrix_address, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    int x, y;
    scanf(" %d %d", &x, &y);
    *matrix_address = (int *)realloc(*matrix_address, ((*row_address) * y) * ((*column_address) * x) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < (*row_address) * y; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*column_address) * x; j++) {
            (*matrix_address)[i * (*column_address * x) + j] = matrix[(i % (*row_address)) * (*column_address) +  j % (*column_address)];
        }
    }
    (*row_address) *= y;
    (*column_address) *= x;
}

void transpose(int *matrix, int **matrix_address, int *row_address, int *column_address)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *row_address; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *column_address; j++) {
            (*matrix_address)[j * (*row_address) + i] = matrix[i * (*column_address) + j];
        }
    }
    // swapping row and column
    int tmp = *row_address;
    *row_address = *column_address;
    *column_address = tmp;
}

int main()
{
    int row, column;
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
    int *matrix = (int *)malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) {
        scanf("%d", matrix + i);
    }

    int *copy_matrix = (int *)malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) {
            copy_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    }
    
    char instruction[20];
    while (1) {
        scanf("%s", instruction);
        //gets(instruction);
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "exit"))
            break;
        for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) {
            copy_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
        }
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "ravel"))
            ravel(copy_matrix, &row, &column);
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "reshape"))
            reshape(&row, &column);
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "resize"))
            resize(&matrix, &row, &column);
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "append_row"))
            append_row(&matrix, &row, &column);
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "insert_row"))
            insert_row(copy_matrix, &matrix, &row, &column);
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "append_column"))
            append_column(copy_matrix, &matrix, &row, &column);
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "insert_column"))
            insert_column(copy_matrix, &matrix, &row, &column);
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "delete_row"))
            delete_row(copy_matrix, &matrix, &row, &column);   
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "delete_column"))
            delete_column(copy_matrix, &matrix, &row, &column);
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "tile"))
            tile(copy_matrix, &matrix, &row, &column);
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "transpose"))
            transpose(copy_matrix, &matrix, &row, &column);
        if (strcmp(instruction, "ravel"))
            print_matrix(matrix, row, column);
    }
    
    free(matrix);
    matrix = NULL;
    free(copy_matrix);
    copy_matrix = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my sample input:

```
3 3
95 61 70
98 84 45
92 21 63
append_row
65 45 28
append_row
66 66 67
insert_column
2
32 40 1 52 52
delete_column
2
insert_column
0
63 98 71 49 94
insert_column
2
57 16 45 75 10
exit
```

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Running your code in a debugger would help you find the location of the segmentation fault.  You can see where it happens and inspect the variables involved for unexpected values.

Comment: When you insert or delete rows or columns, you create a new matrix with a different size, but you still treat `matrix` and `copy_matrix` as having the same size in `main`. Why do you `copy_matrix` anyway?

Comment: You are wasting time if you don't check return codes of I/O operations like `scanf()`

Comment: `foo = realloc(foo, ...)` will leak memory on failure.  Assign the result to a temporary.

Comment: Consider `const` on arguments.  It documents usage.

Comment: Always use a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: Don't cast the `void *` from malloc/realloc in C.

Comment: It segfault in `arena_for_chunk()` of `realloc()` called from `append_row()`. This suggest memory corruption to me.  valgrind reports invalid reads in delete_column and insert_column, and invalid write in `main()` when copying the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is too complicated:

- as you pass the matrix array and dimensions separately, you need to dereference the pointers in far too many places, and it make the code hard to follow.
- in the `main` loop, you pass `copy_matrix` along with the potentially updated `row` and `column` values, but the `copy_matrix` array is never reallocated so it may become too small to handle a copy of the `matrix` values. This explains the segmentation that may be caused by attempting to write beyond the end of the allocated array.

You should use `matrix` structures that include a pointer to the array and the dimensions and pass pointers to these structures to the various handlers.

Here is a modified version for you to study:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct matrix {
    size_t rows, cols;
    int *arr;
} matrix;

#define MATRIX_GET(m, row, col)  ((m)->arr[(m)->cols * (row) + (col)])
#define MATRIX_SET(m, row, col, val)  ((m)->arr[(m)->cols * (row) + (col)] = (val))

/* read and discard the rest of the input line */
int flush_input(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

bool matrix_allocate(matrix *m, int rows, int cols) {
    m->rows = rows;
    m->cols = cols;
    m->arr = calloc(m->rows * m->cols, sizeof(*m->arr));
    if (m->arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate matrix cells\n");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void matrix_deallocate(matrix *m) {
    free(m->arr);
    m->arr = NULL;
}

bool matrix_init(matrix *m) {
    int rows = 0, cols = 0;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        flush_input();
        return false;
    }
    if (rows <= 0 || cols <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid matrix dimensions\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!matrix_allocate(m, rows, cols))
        return 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m->rows * m->cols; i++) {
        m->arr[i] = 0;
        scanf("%d", &m->arr[i]);
    }
    return true;
}

bool matrix_copy(matrix *dest, const matrix *src) {
    matrix_deallocate(dest);
    if (!matrix_allocate(dest, src->rows, src->cols))
        return false;
    memcpy(dest->arr, src->arr, src->rows * src->cols * sizeof(*dest->arr));
    return true;
}

void print_matrix(const matrix *m) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m->cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", MATRIX_GET(m, i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void ravel(const matrix *m) {
    for (size_t i = 0, size = m->rows * m->cols; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", m->arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

bool reshape(matrix *m)
{
    int x, y;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &y, &x) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        flush_input();
        return false;
    }
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid dimensions: %d %d\n", y, x);
        return false;
    }

    size_t new_rows = y;
    size_t new_cols = x;
    size_t new_count = new_rows * new_cols;
    if (new_count != m->rows * m->cols) {
        fprintf(stderr, "total number of elements must be the same\n");
        return false;
    }

    int *new_arr = realloc(m->arr, sizeof(*m->arr) * new_count);
    if (new_arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate matrix cells\n");
        return false;
    }
    m->rows = new_rows;
    m->cols = new_cols;
    m->arr = new_arr;
    return true;
}

bool resize(matrix *m)
{
    int x, y;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &y, &x) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        flush_input();
        return false;
    }
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid dimensions: %d %d\n", y, x);
        return false;
    }

    size_t new_rows = y;
    size_t new_cols = x;
    size_t count = m->rows * m->cols;
    size_t new_count = new_rows * new_cols;
    int *new_arr = realloc(m->arr, sizeof(int) * new_count);
    if (new_arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot reallocate matrix cells\n");
        return false;
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < new_count; i++)
            new_arr[i] = 0;
    } else {
        for (size_t i = count; i < new_count; i++) {
            new_arr[i] = new_arr[i % count];
        }
    }
    m->rows = new_rows;
    m->cols = new_cols;
    m->arr = new_arr;
    return true;
}

bool insert_row_internal(matrix *m, size_t insert)
{
    int row[m->cols];
    for (size_t k = 0; k < m->cols; k++) {
        row[k] = 0;
        scanf("%d", &row[k]);
    }
    size_t new_rows = m->rows + 1;
    int *new_arr = realloc(m->arr, sizeof(*new_arr) * new_rows * m->cols);
    if (new_arr == NULL)
        return false;
    if (insert >= m->rows) {
        insert = m->rows;
    } else
    if (insert < m->rows) {
        memmove(&new_arr[(insert + 1) * m->cols], &new_arr[insert * m->cols],
                sizeof(*new_arr) * (m->rows - insert) * m->cols);
    }
    memcpy(&new_arr[insert * m->cols], row, sizeof(*new_arr) * m->cols);
    m->rows = new_rows;
    m->arr = new_arr;
    return true;
}

bool append_row(matrix *m)
{
    return insert_row_internal(m, m->rows);
}

bool insert_row(matrix *m)
{
    int row = 0;
    if (scanf("%d", &row) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        flush_input();
        return false;
    }
    if (row < 0 || (size_t)row > m->rows) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid row: %d\n", row);
        return false;
    }
    return insert_row_internal(m, row);
}

bool insert_column_internal(matrix *m, size_t insert)
{
    int column[m->rows];
    for (size_t k = 0; k < m->rows; k++) {
        column[k] = 0;
        scanf("%d", &column[k]);
    }
    size_t new_cols = m->cols + 1;
    int *new_arr = realloc(m->arr, sizeof(*new_arr) * m->rows * new_cols);
    if (new_arr == NULL)
        return false;
    if (insert > m->cols)
        insert = m->cols;
    // copy from the end to allow for insertions
    for (size_t i = m->rows; i-- > 0;) {
        for (size_t j = m->cols; j-- > insert;) {
            new_arr[new_cols * i + j + 1] = new_arr[m->cols * i + j];
        }
        new_arr[new_cols * i + insert] = column[i];
        for (size_t j = insert; j-- > 0;) {
            new_arr[new_cols * i + j] = new_arr[m->cols * i + j];
        }
    }
    m->cols = new_cols;
    m->arr = new_arr;
    return true;
}

bool append_column(matrix *m)
{
    return insert_column_internal(m, m->cols);
}

bool insert_column(matrix *m)
{
    int col = 0;
    if (scanf("%d", &col) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        flush_input();
        return false;
    }
    if (col < 0 || (size_t)col > m->cols) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid column: %d\n", col);
        return false;
    }
    return insert_column_internal(m, col);
}

bool delete_row(matrix *m)
{
    int row = 0;
    if (scanf("%d", &row) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        flush_input();
        return false;
    }
    if (row < 0 || (size_t)row >= m->rows) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid row: %d\n", row);
        return false;
    }
    size_t new_rows = m->rows - 1;
    memmove(&m->arr[row * m->cols], &m->arr[(row + 1) * m->cols],
            sizeof(*m->arr) * (m->rows - row - 1) * m->cols);
    int *new_arr = realloc(m->arr, sizeof(*new_arr) * new_rows * m->cols);
    if (new_arr == NULL)
        new_arr = m->arr;
    m->arr = new_arr;
    m->rows = new_rows;
    return true;
}

bool delete_column(matrix *m)
{
    int col = 0;
    if (scanf("%d", &col) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        flush_input();
        return false;
    }
    if (col <= 0 || (size_t)col >= m->cols) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid column: %d\n", col);
        return false;
    }
    size_t new_cols = m->cols - 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < (size_t)col; j++) {
            m->arr[i * new_cols + j] = m->arr[i * m->cols + j];
        }
        for (size_t j = col; j < new_cols; j++) {
            m->arr[i * new_cols + j] = m->arr[i * m->cols + j + 1];
        }
    }
    int *new_arr = realloc(m->arr, sizeof(*new_arr) * m->rows * new_cols);
    if (new_arr == NULL)
        new_arr = m->arr;
    m->arr = new_arr;
    m->cols = new_cols;
    return true;
}

bool tile(matrix *m)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &y, &x) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        flush_input();
        return false;
    }
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || m->cols == 0 || m->rows == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid dimensions\n");
        return false;
    }
    size_t rows = m->rows;
    size_t cols = m->cols;
    size_t new_rows = rows * y;
    size_t new_cols = cols * x;
    int *new_arr = calloc(sizeof(*new_arr), new_rows * new_cols);
    if (new_arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate tiled matrix cells\n");
        return false;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < new_rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < new_cols; j++) {
            new_arr[i * new_cols + j] = m->arr[(i % rows) * cols + (j % cols)];
        }
    }
    free(m->arr);
    m->arr = new_arr;
    m->rows = new_rows;
    m->cols = new_cols;
    return true;
}

bool transpose(matrix *m)
{
    size_t rows = m->rows;
    size_t cols = m->cols;
    int *new_arr = calloc(sizeof(*new_arr), rows * cols);
    if (new_arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate transposed cells\n");
        return false;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            new_arr[j * rows + i] = m->arr[i * cols + j];
        }
    }
    // swapping rows and cols
    m->rows = cols;
    m->cols = rows;
    free(m->arr);
    m->arr = new_arr;
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    matrix m = { 0, 0, NULL };

    if (!matrix_init(&m))
        return 1;

    print_matrix(&m);

    char instruction[20];
    while (scanf("%19s", instruction) == 1) {
        bool success = true;
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "exit")) {
            break;
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "reshape")) {
            success = reshape(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "resize")) {
            success = resize(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "append_row")) {
            success = append_row(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "insert_row")) {
            success = insert_row(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "append_column")) {
            success = append_column(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "insert_column")) {
            success = insert_column(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "delete_row")) {
            success = delete_row(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "delete_column")) {
            success = delete_column(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "tile")) {
            success = tile(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "transpose")) {
            success = transpose(&m);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "ravel")) {
            ravel(&m);
            continue;
        } else
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "print")) {
            print_matrix(&m);
            continue;
        } else
        if (*instruction >= '0' && *instruction <= '9') {
            /* ignore numbers */
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("%s: unknown command\n", instruction);
            continue;
        }
        if (!success) {
            printf("%s: command failed!\n", instruction);
        }
        print_matrix(&m);
    }

    matrix_deallocate(&m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be marked as "the answer". Thanks for the good rewriting the code.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I'm still a begginer in C programming so sometimes couldn't understand some parts of your codes. But I'll mark it as the answer as LORDTEK suggested. Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 1):

1. In `main()` you don't change the size of `copy_matrix` but you change size of  `matrix` (`row` and `column`).  A minimal fix is to recreate the matrix in the `while(1)` loop.

   ```
    while (1) {
        scanf("%19s", instruction);
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "exit"))
            break;
        int* copy_matrix = malloc(row * column * sizeof *copy_matrix);
        if(!copy_matrix)
            exit(1);
        // ...
        free(copy_matrix);
        copy_matrix = NULL;
    }
   ```

   To me it's an internal implementation detail of the functions that change the shape of `matrix` so I suggest you remove the argument and handle it internally in each of the functions that require it.
2. Consider using `memcpy()`.
3. Always use a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflows.
4. (Not fixed) Always check the return value of I/O operations like `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.
5. (Not fixed) `foo = relloc(foo, ...)` leaks memory on failure.  You need a NULL check before overwriting `foo` so use a temporary even if it's `exit(1)` like the strategy.  This will placate `gcc -fanalyzer`.

```
$ ./a.out < input.txt
95 61 70 
98 84 45 
92 21 63 
65 45 28 
95 61 70 
98 84 45 
92 21 63 
65 45 28 
66 66 67 
95 61 32 70 
98 84 40 45 
92 21 1 63 
65 45 52 28 
66 66 52 67 
95 61 70 
98 84 45 
92 21 63 
65 45 28 
66 66 67 
63 95 61 70 
98 98 84 45 
71 92 21 63 
49 65 45 28 
94 66 66 67 
63 95 57 61 70 
98 98 16 84 45 
71 92 45 21 63 
49 65 75 45 28 
94 66 10 66 67
```

Answer (score 0):

So how did I resolve the problem with my own knowledge of programming:
Actually I wrote my code in several ways and still could't get the full mark for the problem. I decalred global variables for matrix, row and column in order to avoid too many dereferences. I changed realloc() to malloc() (but I suppose it could also be done with realloc() too, even neater).

Most importantly, I found out the problem - as you mentioned - was trying to access parts of memory that weren't allocated (for instance, check resize or insert column functions, and also take notice of how this new functions works for border indexes like 0).

Overall, with also other important changes in the algorithm and maybe technical points, this is my final code which got the full score in that question: (still not sure if there may be any testcases which my program will fail at, but at least I'll share it here for fellow beginner programmers with pointers who may have the same problems.)

In my opinion, the whole code can still be written in a much better and neater way but still hope this can be helpful :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int row, column;
int* result_matrix;
int* matrix;
int* copy_matrix;


void shift(int start, int end, int shift_size, int direction)
{
    // direction == 1 right, direction = -1 left
    if (direction == 1) {
        for (int i = end - 1; start <= i; i--) {
            matrix[i + shift_size] = matrix[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            matrix[i - shift_size] = matrix[i];
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            printf("%d ", result_matrix[i * column + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void ravel()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) {
        printf("%d ", result_matrix[i]);
    }
    column *= row;
    row = 1;
    printf("\n");
}

void reshape()
{
    scanf("\n%d %d", &row, &column);
}

int min (int a, int b) {
    if (a <= b) return a;
    return b;
}

void resize()
{
    int first_size = row * column;
    scanf("\n%d %d", &row, &column);
    matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < min(first_size, row * column); i++) matrix[i] = result_matrix[i];
    free(result_matrix);
    for (int iterator = first_size; iterator < row * column; iterator++) {
        matrix[iterator] = matrix[iterator % first_size];
    }
    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) result_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    free(matrix);
}

void append_row()
{
    matrix = (int*) malloc((row + 1) * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) matrix[i] = result_matrix[i];
    free(result_matrix);
    int new_row[column];
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        scanf("\n%d", &new_row[j]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        matrix[row * column + j] = new_row[j];
    }
    row++;
    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) result_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    free(matrix);
}

void insert_row()
{
    matrix = (int*) malloc((row + 1) * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) matrix[i] = result_matrix[i];
    free(result_matrix);

    int insert;
    scanf("\n%d", &insert);
    int new_row[column];
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        scanf("\n%d", &new_row[j]);
    }
    
    shift(insert * column, row * column, column, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        matrix[insert * column + i] = new_row[i];
    }
    row++;

    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) result_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    free(matrix);
}

void append_column()
{
    matrix = (int*) malloc(row * (column + 1) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) matrix[i] = result_matrix[i];
    free(result_matrix);

    int new_column[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        scanf("\n%d", &new_column[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        shift(i * (column + 1) + column, row * column + i, 1, 1);
        matrix[i * (column + 1) + column] = new_column[i];
    }
    column++;
    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) result_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    free(matrix);
}

void insert_column()
{
    matrix = (int*) malloc(row * (column + 1) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) matrix[i] = result_matrix[i];
    free(result_matrix);
    int insert;
    scanf("\n%d", &insert);
    int new_column[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        scanf("\n%d", &new_column[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        shift(i * (column + 1) + insert, row * column + i, 1, 1);
        matrix[i * (column + 1) + insert] = new_column[i];
    }
    column++;
    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) result_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    free(matrix);
}

void delete_row()
{
    matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) matrix[i] = result_matrix[i];
    free(result_matrix);
    
    int delete;
    scanf("\n%d", &delete);
    if (delete < row - 1) {
        shift((delete+1) * column, row * column, column, -1);
    } 
    row--;

    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) result_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    free(matrix);
}

void delete_column()
{
    matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) matrix[i] = result_matrix[i];
    free(result_matrix);

    int delete;
    scanf("\n%d", &delete);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        shift(i * (column - 1) + delete + 1, row * column - i, 1, -1);
    }
    column--;

    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) result_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    free(matrix);
}

void tile()
{
    int x, y;
    scanf("\n%d %d", &y, &x);
    matrix = (int*) malloc(row * x * column * y * sizeof(int));
    int* tmp = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) tmp[i] = result_matrix[i];
    free(result_matrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < row * y; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column * x; j++) {
            matrix[i * (column * x) + j] = tmp[(i % row) * column +  j % column];
        }
    }
    row *= y;
    column *= x;

    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) result_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    free(matrix);
}

void transpose()
{
    matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) matrix[i] = result_matrix[i];
    free(result_matrix);

    copy_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) copy_matrix[i] = matrix[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            matrix[i * row + j] = copy_matrix[j * column + i];
        }
    }

    // swapping row and column
    int tmp = row;
    row = column;
    column = tmp;

    free(copy_matrix);
    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) result_matrix[i] = matrix[i];
    free(matrix);
}

int main()
{
    // input
    scanf("\n%d %d", &row, &column);
    result_matrix = (int*) malloc(row * column * sizeof(int));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) {
        scanf("\n%d", result_matrix + i);
    }
    
    char instruction[20];
    while (1) {
        scanf("\n%s", instruction);
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "exit")) break;
        if (!strcmp(instruction, "ravel")) ravel();
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "reshape")) reshape();
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "resize")) resize();
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "append_row")) append_row();
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "insert_row")) insert_row();
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "append_column")) append_column();
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "insert_column")) insert_column();
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "delete_row")) delete_row();   
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "delete_column")) delete_column();
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "tile")) tile();
        else if (!strcmp(instruction, "transpose")) transpose();
        if (strcmp(instruction, "ravel")) print_matrix();
    }
    
    free(result_matrix); result_matrix = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```